# Remove comment from Chatter post

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed, feedcomment

I would like to remove the option to comment on the post made in the Chatter feed.
Does anyone know if it is possible and how to do it?

[image: Remove comment from Chatter]

Comment: Is this in experience cloud?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all users who are assigned a profile with the feed post editing permissions enabled can edit their posts and comments. If needed, you can disable feed post editing for all users in your organization, regardless of their assigned user profile. You can also shut off post and comment editing for all users assigned the “Can Approve Feed Post and Comment” permission.

- From Setup, enter Chatter Settings in the Quick Find box, then select
  Chatter Settings.
- Click Edit.
- In the Post and Comment Modification section, deselect the checkbox
  on Allow users to edit posts and comments.  Click Save.
- If you have assigned the “Can Approve Feed Post and Comment”
  permission, disable that on the relevant permission sets. “Can
  Approve Feed Post and Comment” lets assigned users edit and delete
  any post or comment in any Chatter feed those users have access to.
  This permission is available under Setup | Permission Sets | Select a
  permission set | System Permissions.

Check [Disable Edit Feed Post for All Users](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_admin_feeds_edit_posts_disable.htm&type=5).

Answer (score -1):

Did this work for you? For me it removes the 'edit' option... but users are still able to comment...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210960)